# Error Message not appearing in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am writing a code to ensure parent record is not deleted when there is a child record associated to it.

The code is as follows

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :number
  has_many :customer_bills

  before_destroy :check_for_bills

  private

  def check_for_bills
    if customer_bills.count > 0
     errors.add :base, "cannot delete customer while Bills exist"
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

### View

```
<% if flash[:error] -%>
    <p class='error'><%=h flash[:error] %></p>
  <% end -%>
```

### Controller

```
def destroy
..
flash[:error] = @customer.errors
..
end
```

But I am not getting the error message though the code is working properly? what seems to be the problem? Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually displaying the error in your template or view?

Comment: i added @customer.errors in the index but that did not work out. what changes must i do in the controller and the view?

Comment: can you show us the index view?

Comment: sure. i have updated the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Rails 3.2 we have to use `notice` instead of `flash`.

### View

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
```

Just try the above code and appropriate styles also

### CSS

```
#notice {
color: #000 !important;
border: 2px solid red;
padding: 1em;
margin-bottom: 2em;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
font: bold smaller sans-serif;
}
```

You can add errors like before

### Adding Error

```
def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
  if line_items.empty?
    return true
  else
    errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
    return false
  end
end
```

I'm learning rails, not sure above is the perfect solution....